# Is there a way to split polygons by several lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, line

I have a polygon (.shp) and a line (.shp) layer. I want to split the polygon in several pieces along the lines that overlap the polygon. Afterwards I want to edit each polygon separately (attribute table).

I tried a workaround: Buffering the lines with a small distance and then it worked with the geoprocessing tools (difference - "Unterschied"). Afterwards "multipart to singlepart". It worked but I rather like to do it with lines.

Is there an extension for QGIS or another way to do the task? Similar to the ESRI ArcINFO tool "Split Polygons With Lines"? But all I have is QGIS 2.6.

[image: Polygon - green; line - red]

Answer (score 2):

The [Digitizing Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/) plugin will do the trick.
One of the tools in that plugin is called "Split Selected Features With Selected Lines from Another Layer"
[image]

Comment: Have you tried dissolving all the line segments together and then running the tool?

Comment: I tried this before but it was only possible to select ONE line. The polygon was split into two parts. I would like to split the polygon with several lines into several parts. If I try it with more than one line a pop up occurs: "Aufteilen: Es gibt 12 gewählte Objekte im Layer testlinie. Bitte wählen Sie nur ein Objekt aus, mit dem aufgeteilt werden soll." I have the german version installed.

Comment: Hi HDunn, thanks for your quick comment! I dissolved the 12 lines together. In the attribute table was only one field I selected. Than I started editing the polygon layer and selected the layer. Tried the "Split Selected Features With Selected Lines from Another Layer" tool, but nothing happened. The polygon was not split into several parts.

Comment: The line must cross the polygon

Comment: The tool is "Split selected features with selected LINE from another layer". This is an extremely important distinction given the problem faced by the original and others like myself who don't want to have to go line by line to execute our tasks.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an answer that works for QGIS 3+**

The "Split Selected Features" tool has been removed in Digitizing Tools Version 1.4.0

The documentation says:
Use processing's in-place editing Split with lines instead.

*To find that in QGIS 3.4, do this:*
[image]

````
Go to Processing Toolbox (Ctrl + Alt + T),
scroll down to the Vector Overlay group,
and choose "Split with lines"```
````