# Fill out irregular grid with polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, grids-graticules

I'm using QGIS 3.10.0 A Coruna. 
As you see in the picture, I have an unregular grid with some buildings on them. I would like to fill out all the other rectangles between the points with a polygon automatically. That means every 4 points should create a seperate polygon. Is there a possibility to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a polygon that completely covers your study area, then use a `Difference` tool with the buildings layer as the Overlay Layer. Then use `Split With Lines` using the line layer as the Overlay Layer.

Comment: Thanks, the idea was good, but Splitting with Lines just wasnt working. I came across a different thread that helped with thas part: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130949/is-there-a-way-to-split-polygons-by-several-lines-in-qgis